# Как решить проблему с типами?

Tags: typescript

```
let a = {
    a: () => 1,
    b: () => 2,
}

let d = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
}

let dd = a[d.a]()
```

Как это разрешить?

> TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ a: () => number; b: () => number; }'.   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ a: () => number; b: () => number; }'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно вот так.

```
interface Some<T> {
  [key: string]: T;
}

let a: Some<() => number> = {
  a: () => 1,
  b: () => 2
};

let d: Some<string> = {
  a: "a",
  b: "b"
};

let dd = a[d.a]();
```